# $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field $\iff F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is an integral domain

Tags: ring-theory

$$\color{red}{Is~my~interpretation~correct?}$$

Let $F$ be a field. I know that $p(x)\in F[x]$ is irreducible $\iff \langle p(x)\rangle$ is maximal i.e.

- **$F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field $\iff p(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x].$**

I want to obtain an analogous result for integral domain. I know that for any integral domain $D,$ $p(x)(\ne0)\in D[x]$ is prime $\iff \langle p(x)\rangle$ is prime ideal. So

- **For $p(x)(\ne 0)\in D[x],~D[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is an integral domain $\iff\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a prime ideal.**

So for $p(x)(\ne0)\in F[x],F$ being a field,

- **$F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is an integral domain $\iff \langle p(x)\rangle$ is a prime ideal $\iff p(x)$ is prime $\Rightarrow p(x)$ is irreducible $\iff F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field.**

> **So for any field $F$ and for any $p(x)\in F[x],F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field $\iff F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is an integral domain.**

Comment: Yes, that's true...but be careful to explicitly explain all that, lest someone will believe you're implying that something's a field iff it is an integral domain.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Sure.

Comment: @SritiMallick The phenomenon you're looking at is that $R/P$ is a domain iff $P$ is a prime ideal. It's also true that $R/P$ is a field iff $P$ is a maximal ideal. Since all the nonzero prime ideals in a PID are maximal, that is how you got the situation in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true only provided you exclude $p(x)=0$ (which you did en route, but not in the final statement). The zero ideal of a principal ideal domain is prime (because of the "domain"), but not maximal (unless the PID is itself a field), and it is the only non-maximal prime ideal.

A direct way to see the equivalence is that, assuming $p(x)\neq0$, the ring $R=F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a finite dimensional vector space over the field$~F$. The operation of multiplication by any element $a\in R$ is an $F$-linear operator on $R$; it will be injective ($a$ is regular in $R$) if and only if it is surjective ($a$ is invertible in $R$, as $1\in R$ is a multiple of it) if and only it its determinant is nonzero. In particulat all nonzero $a$ are regular ($R$ is an integral domain, and $\langle p(x)\rangle$ prime) if and only if all nonzero $a$ are invertible ($R$ is a field, and $\langle p(x)\rangle$ maximal).